# R: Keep getting "object 'MA' not found" when trying to create subset despite MA definitely being in there

Tags: r

While this may end up being obvious, I can't figure it out or find anything quite like it (similar questions I've found are cases of people not having the variable or value they're looking for or bug reports on more complex operations. Could it have something to do with the sheer scale of my dataset?

My relevant code is:

> MaOnly <- NfirsManipulated[NfirsManipulated$STATE == MA, ]

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(NfirsManipulated, NfirsManipulated$STATE == MA,  : 
object 'MA' not found
```

> summary(NfirsManipulated$STATE)

```
AK    AL    AR    AZ    CA    CO    CT    DC    DE    FL    GA    HI 
1958  8279 13888  3857 22591  4961  4184   435  1267 29443 23264   857 
IA    ID    IL    IN    KS    KY    LA    MA    MD    ME    MI    MN 
4597  2545 24406 10496  7308  9871 12892  8845  7110  1762 34481  9784 
MO    MS    MT    NA    NC    ND    NE    NH    NJ    NM    NV    NY 
14141 12865  1284    53 18763   782  2437  1850  8909  2792  2806 17119 
OH    OK    OR    PA    PR    RI    SC    SD    TN    TX    UT    VA 
33855  9798  5897  8412     0   703 10951   817 18468 39645  2160 14660 
VT    WA    WI    WV    WY  NA's 
913  9831  7096  7901   499  1518
```

> MaOnly <- NfirsManipulated[NfirsManipulated$STATE == MA, ]

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(NfirsManipulated, NfirsManipulated$STATE == MA,  : 
object 'MA' not found
```

> MaOnly <- NfirsManipulated[which(NfirsManipulated$STATE == MA), ]

```
Error in which(NfirsManipulated$STATE == MA) : object 'MA' not found
```

> MaOnly <- subset(NfirsManipulated,STATE == MA)

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'MA' not found
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: MA needs to be in quotes, unless you have an object called MA

Comment: For instance, try `MaOnly <- NfirsManipulated[NfirsManipulated$STATE == "MA", ]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to tell R to look for the right kind of data, a character string, so when setting the subset use`STATE=="MA"` .

The best way to be sure is to run a structure inquiry.

```
str(NfirsManipulated$STATE)
```

It will tell you what kind of data you are looking for and how to properly format and address it. If it is a character you need the `"  "` around it.